# Pokemon-like manga. A boy forms a bond with a blue-skinned demon from a Gashapon machine

Tags: story-identification, manga

The manga I seek is about a boy forming a Pokemon like bond with a blue skinned humanoid demon-like creature, who he releases from a Gashapon Machine. I'm certain it's not *Yo-kai Watch*.

Comment: Please [edit] and split this into separate questions. Also, the third question falls afoul of our list policy as per the [tour].

Comment: :) If you would, please post each manga request in a separate question. That way, if two people answer it, both can be designated as the "correct" answer. If you have not, I do recommend the [tour]. It will also tell you how to accept answers.

Comment: Feel free to post the second manga request in a new question (you can view history by clicking on the "edited ... ago" link above). You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons. Wrong answers give you an excellent opportunity to [edit] the question with new details that you've realized because they don't match a current answer.

Answer (score 1):

This may be [*Yo-kai Watch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yo-kai_Watch_(manga))

[image: Cover of first volume of Yo-kai Watch]

> **Nathan "Nate" Adams** (天野景太, Amano Keita) – An 11-year-old 5th grader who acquires a Yo-kai Watch while bug hunting in the Mount Wildwood forest. He's portrayed as a relatively average and straightforward character.[5]
>
> **Whisper** (ウィスパー, Wisupā) – Nate's self-appointed Yo-kai butler, who had been trapped in a gashapon machine for over one-hundred years before being freed by Nate. In addition to giving Nate the Yo-kai Watch, he also explains the different characteristics and traits of Yo-kai when he and Nate run into them.

Comment: The Manga I seek existed Before Yo-Kai Watch! The Monster Companion was More Humanoid!